# How do I extract video frames for editing one at a time?

Tags: ffmpeg, video, graphicsmagick

I'm trying to apply graphicsmagick v1.3.42 filters/resizing to frames from videos extracted with ffmpeg v6.1.

The process of extracting and resizing all frames uses alot of space, I want to iterate and edit each frame individually if thats possible?

I use: `ffmpeg6 -i "input_video.mp4" output_frames/frame%04d.png` to get the frames.

then:

```sh
for filename in  output_frames/*.png; do
    gm convert "$filename" -median 2 -filter Mitchell -resize 400% -unsharp 0x0.75+0.75+0.008 "$filename"
done
# Reassemble video from frames and audio
ffmpeg6 -i output_frames/frame%04d.png -i input.mp3 -c:v libx264 -r 25 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy -shortest output_video.mp4
```

Answer (score 1):

Limit yourself to key frames. Use this ffmpeg option.

```
-skip_frame nokey
```

Comment: ok i'll try thanks, can that be used to edit the frame and insert it back into the video or append to a new file?

Comment: There is no need to extract the images and then reassemble them again. You can use the scale ffmpeg filter to directly convert to a scaled up/down video. There is also an unsharp filter. Do a search of `ffmpeg -filters` output to see if what you want to do can be done with just ffmpeg.

Comment: thanks, I've already done alot of experimenting with ffmpeg filters, just thought that something like graphicsmagick would be better. also testing one image is faster but I found how to cut a video and now i'm just testing on a 10sec chunk.

Comment: one thing is i'd like to use potrace/mkbitmap to vectorize the whole thing. i wonder if there's a vector video format